# How bad are covid vaccines?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, side-effects

For the past year I've been hearing about people claiming that those who took the covid jabs are dropping like flies. I even hear people claim that the covid vaccinations are depopulation tools and most people who get it are going to die within the next 10 years! As someone who (reluctantly) took the jabs in May 2021, this concerns me and I'm sure there are millions of people like me. If you go on bitchute there seems to be a lot of evidence in support of that notion and it worries me. I also hear about people on the internet saying that they or someone they know are having some nasty side effects. But today darkmatter2525 made a video saying that the whole "died suddenly" thing is just the frequency illusion and that claims saying that athletes are collapsing more than ever is just based on misleading data. Every time someone under 70 years old dies a lot of people are blaming the vaccine. But what's the truth? I know there's some truth to what these "anti-vaxxers" saying but just how bad is it and what exactly is going on? Should I be concerned for myself and my loved ones?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, your question will be closed because it lacks research (see the [on-topic policy](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). Questions and answers here work on the basis of current medical evidence, not on anecdote (your observations are anecdote - no data to back them up). Having said all that - have a look at the official sources of the CDC, WHO etc and look at the numbers. There is no evidence that the vaccine is harming significant numbers of people or going to kill people, and the rates of harm are much less than COVID infection.

Comment: `there's some truth to what these "anti-vaxxers" saying` -- No there isn't. Every word out of their mouths is a lie. Every single word.

Comment: You really need to try to get your "news" somewhere more reliable. Die-hard anti-vaxers will swear - as they are dying of covid - that they do not have covid. Some beg for the vaccine when it's too late and they're already dying. Look at the real numbers, not "I heard that..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I'll bite...

I'm assuming you are from the USA, based on your post about sporting people collapsing (note - not dying AFAIK. Not being an American, I don't follow their sports), one of which made news headlines.  [John's Hopkins](https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/vaccines/us-states#vaccination-rollout-us) has some information on vaccine uptake in the USA, which indicates at least 50% of people in all states got a full course of the vaccine.

Now, note that 50% means 1 in every 2 people - if people were dropping dead, wouldn't you expect to be hearing of massive surges of death right now (at the time of writing: Feb 2023) - like half the people at your work/school/church?

I found a paper published by a big group of people known as the [Cochrane Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochrane_(organisation)), which is a British organization dedicated to helping people make evidence based health decisions. They are now international, and the study is authored by a range of people, mostly from Europe, but also South Africa and Chile.

In this study (read for free at [PubMed Central](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9726273/)) they looked at vaccine effectiveness and safety for the COVID vaccines - looking at 12 vaccines, mixed vaccine schedules (i.e. people taking different types/makes of vaccines), different exposure times, ages etc as explained in the technical parts of the paper, but for those who aren't scientists, it has non-technical summaries:

> We found 41 worldwide studies involving 433,838 people assessing 12 different vaccines. Thirty‐five studies included only healthy people who had never had COVID‐19. Thirty‐six studies included only adults, two only adolescents, two children and adolescents, and one included adolescents and adults. Three studied people with weakened immune systems, and none studied pregnant women.
>
> Most cases assessed results less than six months after the primary vaccination. Most received co‐funding from academic institutions and pharmaceutical companies. Most studies compared a COVID‐19 vaccine with placebo. Five evaluated the addition of a 'mix and match' booster dose.

Anyway... on to answer the question. In the words of the study:

> For the Pfizer, CoronaVac, Sinopharm‐Beijing, and Novavax vaccines, there is insufficient evidence to determine whether there was a difference between the vaccine and placebo mainly because the number of serious adverse events was low.
>
> Moderna, AstraZeneca, Janssen, and Bharat vaccines probably result in no or little difference in the number of serious adverse events.

This indicates that out of the 400,000 odd people they looked at (admittedly over less than 6 months in most cases, but we'd only had the vaccines for a 18 months or so at the time of writing), there were no effects that they could see that indicated problems over and above giving a fake vaccination. For the Pfizer, all cause mortality was 68 per 100,000, but placebo was 64/100,000. This indicates that for every 100,000 people between 60 and 70 people will die **from any cause** after the administration of the working vaccine **OR** a fake (placebo) vaccine. Similarish numbers are seen for the other types of vaccines, though typically lower deaths (<50/100,000) for more traditional types (inactivated virus, protein subunit, etc.).

Now, there is one significant adverse event associated with the mRNA vaccines (the new type - Pfizer/BioNTech and Moderna), which is myocarditis. This is a heart problem which can occur with some infections, such as influenza virus, common cold viruses, bacteria and fungal infection. It can also be caused by the SARS-COV-2 (Covid) virus itself too, and is a result of the spike protein interacting with the tissues of the heart. This is the one that athletes are concerned about, because strenuous exercise puts a strain on the heart itself. However, if you refer to the figures in my answer [here](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/29184/does-this-covid-19-vaccine-study-suggests-a-1-to-718-rate-of-adverse-effects/29207#29207) about vaccine adverse effects, you will see that the virus causes these effects at a higher or equal rate to the vaccine, but the vaccine reduces your overall risk of adverse events and death significantly compared to SARS-CoV-2 infection.

[Based on the table given](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/29184/does-this-covid-19-vaccine-study-suggests-a-1-to-718-rate-of-adverse-effects) in the question I am answering in the linked post in the paragraph above, we would expect to see myocarditis in 1-5 people per 100,000 vaccinated with the BioNTech vaccine. This is a pretty small number, certainly not the millions you should be seeing if the vaccine were really affecting/killing lots of people...

TLDR: no evidence to support the claims.

Source information:

Graña C, Ghosn L, Evrenoglou T, Jarde A, Minozzi S, Bergman H, Buckley BS, Probyn K, Villanueva G, Henschke N, Bonnet H, Assi R, Menon S, Marti M, Devane D, Mallon P, Lelievre JD, Askie LM, Kredo T, Ferrand G, Davidson M, Riveros C, Tovey D, Meerpohl JJ, Grasselli G, Rada G, Hróbjartsson A, Ravaud P, Chaimani A, Boutron I. Efficacy and safety of COVID-19 vaccines. Cochrane Database Syst Rev. 2022 Dec 7;12(12):CD015477. doi: https://doi.org/10.1002/14651858.CD015477. PMID: 36473651; PMCID: PMC9726273.